# Perform one last function before application closes

Tags: python

I have a Python file that is constantly using the `f.write()` function to write to another text file, however, the script doesn't stop writing to the file until it's closed manually.

This is all fine and dandy, except for the fact that any delay greater than 0.01 doesn't seem to save my edits to the text file, so doing a little bit of investigation, an easy fix is the `f.close()` function.

So what I need is a line of code that can detect once the script has been stopped, and put out one last function before being fully closed.

Comment: You seem to have decided that that is the solution to your problem, but I don't think it is. Nobody will be able to identify an actual solution without seeing your code, though. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: What you may be looking for is [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/atexit.html).

Answer (score 2):

If the script has been stopped it cannot execute any more functions. Why not wrap your code in `while(true)` or while some boolean and then instead of exiting the script entirely, just break the loop? That would achieve the same effect.